# How to trigger bootstrap's mouseover effect programmatically

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

In twitter bootstrap, some elements get "greyed out" when the mouse hovers over them. This is true of [buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-single) and [linked list group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked) items. Two examples are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pyfK.jpg

Can this effect be triggered programmatically? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

If the effect were being caused by a css class, one could simply apply the class to the element, like this:

```
$('<my_element>').addClass('bootstrapMouseoverGrey')
```

This doesn't work, though, because the effect isn't caused by a class. It's caused by a pseudoclass. Pseudoclasses can't be added programmatically.

One workaround is to create a new actual class with the exact same definition as the pseudoclass. In my case, the pseudoclass is `a.list-group-item:hover`, defined in bootstrap.css.

```
a.list-group-item:hover,
a.list-group-item:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

I edited bootstrap.css to make a new (actual) class, `bootstrapMouseoverGrey`, with the same definition as the pseudoclass.

```
a.list-group-item:hover,
a.list-group-item:focus,
.bootstrapMouseoverGrey {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Now, I can just add this class to an element using the line at the top of the answer. This gives me the result I want. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Using the 'onmouseover' attribute. It is quite similar to the 'onclick', except obviously for hovering instead.

Like the 'onclick', you will have to include a java script function that would change the css style for that element.

Depending on what you are trying to have this effect on, you could either put it right into the tag that is the object, or use `<span></span>`.

Ex:

```
<div onmouseover="fade()">

    <p>text to fade</p>

</div>

Javascript:
    function fade(){
        code to change style
    }
```

should be straight forward, this would fade everything inside the div (including the background)

Comment: On a side note, dB's answer farther down is more elegant than this. This is a much more conventional way of doing it, and his way is much newer and easier. I would do it that way personally.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
var event = jQuery.Event('<event_name>');
event.stopPropagation();
$('<selector>').trigger(event);
```

Taken from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).